# Phoenix not returning any rows from HBASE view

Tags: hbase, apache-phoenix

I have a table in hbase that *definitely* contains data:

```
scan "my_table", {LIMIT=>1}
 000008d624784f434ea441eb930eb84e201511162015111624000024498 column=g:orig_ccy, timestamp=3688201677984955, value=XXX
```

However, after creating a view over the top of this table in phoenix, no rows were returned:

```
select * from "my_table";
No rows selected (4.033 seconds)
```

Using phoenix version 4.2 on HBASE 0.98.4 (old I know).

Answer (score 1):

Underlying problem is that the time on all of the cells was not a valid unixtime.

Phoenix actually implictly filters over all times.

Putting phoenix into debug really   helped here, see https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/48962/how-to-enable-debug-logging-for-phoenix.html.

> 16/11/16 11:48:40 DEBUG iterate.SerialIterators: Id:
>   7b133b01-9d84-4279-99c1-1a544740f587, Time: 0ms, Scan:
>   {"timeRange":[0,1479296915809],"batch":-1,"startRow":"fa4fa4dc","stopRow":"","loadColumnFamiliesOnDemand":null,"totalColumns":1,"cacheBlocks":true,"families":{"g":["ALL"]},"maxResultSize":-1,"maxVersions":1,"filter":"FilterList
>   AND (2/2): [PageFilter 5, ]","caching":100}

Updating our loading method so it loads *valid* unix datetimes helped out.